# Anyone knows how to calculate the sum of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{999} \log_{10}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right) $$

Can anybody help me how to calculate this summation?

Comment: Sorry this is the first time I'm using this so I had no idea how to properly put an equation so there is an image

Comment: Hint: logarithms turn products into sums.

Comment: Yeah I figured that part and got log10(1000!) - log10(999!) but don't know how to derive that one without using wolfram alpha

Comment: Keep it as a product: there's lots of cancellations.

Comment: After converting the term to a difference of two terms, write out the first several terms of the summation and the last term of the summation. You should see that some of the terms cancel out.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean! Thanks very much!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track! Like Minh Nguyen Nhat, you have to take $\log(1000!)-\log(999!)$ as $\log(1000!/999!)$ to get the answer.

$\log(2/1)+\log(3/2)+\log(4/3)+$...$+\log(1000/999)=\log(1000!/999!)=\log(1000)=3$

Comment: Yeah I figured it out thank you!!!

Comment: hello @Muchang Bahng, you can use MathJax to improve your answers and help more people in a more beatiful way here is a link that could be useful for you https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference